# Saxon xslt import issue

Tags: xml, xslt, apache-camel, saxon

We have a xslt which imports multiple xslts.

The xslt is called as below in camel route

```
<to uri="xslt:Saveaccount/Main.xslt.xslt?saxon=true"/>
```

Main.xslt imports Building.xslt and Policy.xslt in saveaccount.

Building.xslt imports  Saveaccount/peril/wind/building.xslt,Saveaccount/peril/flood/building.xslt and 
Saveaccount/peril/Thunderstrom/building.xslt

Policy.xslt imports  Saveaccount/peril/wind/Policy.xslt,Saveaccount/peril/flood/Policy.xslt and 
Saveaccount/peril/Thunderstrom/Policy.xslt

```
Folder structure is as below

Saveaccount
Main.xslt
Building.xslt
Policy.xslt

Saveaccount/peril/wind
building.xslt
Policy.xslt

Saveaccount/peril/flood
building.xslt
Policy.xslt

Saveaccount/peril/Thunderstrom
building.xslt
Policy.xslt
```

We are getting compilation error while using saxon.

```
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Failed to compile stylesheet. 12 errors detected.
    at net.sf.saxon.PreparedStylesheet.prepare(PreparedStylesheet.java:249) [Saxon-HE-9.5.1-5.jar:]
    at net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:142) [Saxon-HE-9.5.1-5.jar:]
    at org.apache.camel.builder.xml.XsltBuilder.setTransformerSource(XsltBuilder.java:353) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630310.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630310]
    at org.apache.camel.component.xslt.XsltEndpoint.loadResource(XsltEndpoint.java:367) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630310.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630310]
    at org.apache.camel.component.xslt.XsltEndpoint.doStart(XsltEndpoint.java:432) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630310.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630310]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630310.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630310]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startService(DefaultCamelContext.java:3251) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630310.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630310]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doAddService(DefaultCamelContext.java:1219) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630310.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630310]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.addService(DefaultCamelContext.java:1180) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630310.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630310]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.addService(DefaultCamelContext.java:1176) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630310.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630310]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:585) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630310.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630310]
    ... 46 more
```

Since the error details are not available in logs any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you validated your stylesheets outside of Camel? Also, since you are using Red Hat, you are better off going to them to ask for support.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to find some way of getting access to the actual error messages. If you can't do that, then all your future XSLT development is going to be like working blindfolded. That's essentially a Camel issue rather than a Saxon issue: Saxon puts the error information wherever the calling application asks for it, defaulting to the System.err output stream.

Comment: There are some notes on how to get error output here: http://camel.apache.org/xslt but I don't use Camel so I can't help you in any more detail.

Comment: Hi Michael, Can I use JAVA API of saxon to find the compile time issues, without using camel. If there is any, can you please guide with steps?